# iPhone ImageIO not returning all metadata of picture

Tags: objective-c, metadata, exif, javax.imageio

I am currently trying to make a simple library for accessing picture metadata in an object oriented way (no more dictionaries). I encountered a lot of strange bugs :

1. Even if `kCGImagePropertyMakerMinoltaDictionary`, `kCGImagePropertyMakerFujiDictionary`, `kCGImagePropertyMakerOlympusDictionary`, `kCGImagePropertyMakerPentaxDictionary` keys are defined, I get an error when compiling my project saying they are undefined :

   Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
     "_kCGImagePropertyMakerMinoltaDictionary", referenced from:
         -[SYMetadata metadataMakerMinolta] in SYMetadata.o
   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
2. `kCGImagePropertyExifBodySerialNumber` is a defined key too from `ImageIO/CGImageProperties.h` but when loading the project in iOS 5.1.1 I get an error saying it is not available :

   dyld: Symbol not found: _kCGImagePropertyExifBodySerialNumber
     Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/0D8144E6-6313-4347-B503-247F5ACC0A11/ConnectTIG.app/ConnectTIG
     Expected in: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
    in /var/mobile/Applications/0D8144E6-6313-4347-B503-247F5ACC0A11/ConnectTIG.app/ConnectTIG
3. Apple has a lot of possibles metadata dictionary keys available, for instance `kCGImagePropertyMakerNikonDictionary`, that exist but are not working. For example I have a picture taken with my Nikon D3100 : when I open it with Preview app on my mac I can access Nikon metadata, but when I get all keys and values on the iPhone I don't have these information.

I am running XCode 4.5.2 (last stable build AFAIK) on Moutain Lion 10.8.2. I tried compiling/running on device and simulator, same results.

As this will be a public library I already have it all on my github repo : https://github.com/dvkch/SYPictureMetadata

Those willing to discover where those bugs come from are welcomed to play around with the code and submit push requests any time.

If you have any possible idea it will be very appreciated !

Stan

Comment: So, I'm a little confused by your question as written.  Are you moving files taken with your Nikon D3100 to your iPhone?  I mean, there's no reason this key would be in a picture taken on the iPhone right - it's not a Nikon.  ??

Comment: sorry, I tried to transfer it by mail, and also used an EyeFi card. Neither of those worked, unless I used NEF format.

Comment: I also did it with importing files as resources in my app. Please consult my repository and build the example app, you will quickly be able to reproduce these bugs.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if the image still has the metadata you are talking about when it arrives on the phone.  Wondering if this is being stripped during the copy. That's why I was asking.  Be interesting to transfer to the phone and then back to the computer and see if it still works on the computer.

Comment: I did it. I included the images as resources of the app then used iFunBox to get them back, opened them and saw that all the metadata were still here. Apparently I'm not the only one having the problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12224530/is-the-metadata-return-from-alassetrepresentation-incomplete?rq=1

Comment: and even when using assets (stored when received by mail, extracted with Image Capture on Mac) metadata don't seem to be stripped, but sill I don't have the info I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly sure there is something wrong with the SDK. The error you're getting is a symbol that is defined in the SDK but doesn't actually exist. I've checked your project and you have included the ImageIO.framework where they're all defined, and indeed all the other keys work fine. kCGImagePropertyMakerNikonCameraSerialNumber works but kCGImagePropertyMakerMinoltaDictionary does not.

If you have a look at the top of the documentation for CGImageProperties it says the framework is "ApplicationServices/ImageIO". This is impossible, ApplicationServices doesn't exist on iOS. At least one error in this documentation already. Clearly they've copied the OSX documentation verbatim.

I'd definitely file a bug report on this problem and the documentation.

FWIW on OSX those keys (likely the same on iOS) are as follows:

```
{MakerCanon}
{MakerNikon}
{MakerMinolta}
{MakerFuji}
{MakerOlympus}
{MakerPentax}
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I thought. Do you have any ideas about point 2 ? Is that the same issue ? What about the 3 ?

Comment: Oh and if you have any way in head to make code compile with or without use of `kCGImagePropertyExifBodySerialNumber ` for instance, I would love to have my methods work under iOS 5.0 and return always nil, and have it really use the key for versions superior to 6.0.

Comment: bug report filled, I hope they will have answers. I already filled a bug about not working iOS simulator on version 5.1 and never got an answer

Comment: I think point #2 is the same thing, but I haven't looked into it or confirmed that.

Comment: Point #3 sounds like the meta data was never intended to be on iOS. I had something similar when I tried out CoreImage on iOS. There was a method to convert a GL texture to a CIImage, and I found it didn't work. The method was promptly removed from the SDK when I reported. (I think iOS 6 they returned it and actually built it)

Comment: If I'm right about point #3, you might not want to bother with the meta data, but I doubt that's good enough. Given that it is defined but not actually available to be linked against, I don't really know of way to detect that at compile time. Someone better with compilers might know more.

Comment: Can you sync images to your iDevice with meta data, and then pull them back off the device with meta data intact? I think that will tell you something about what Apple intends with the SDK. If it's all still there, maybe they'll fix up the SDK next iOS version?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22163/discussion-between-v01d-and-dvkch)